# Spy on Angular5 component not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, spy

My component has the following function:

```
  updateTransactions() {
    let notes = this.createNotes()

    let delTransactions = this.createDelTransactions()
    this.noteService.createNote(notes[0])
    this.noteService.getNoteCreated().subscribe((res) => {
      notes.shift();
      if(res && notes.length > 0) {
        this.noteService.createNote(notes[0])
      } else {
        this.deliverableTransactionService.updateDeliverableTransaction(delTransactions[0].id, delTransactions[0])
      }
    })

    this.deliverableTransactionService.getUpdateDeliverableTransactionStatus().subscribe((res) => {
      delTransactions.shift();
      if(res && delTransactions.length > 0) {
        this.deliverableTransactionService.updateDeliverableTransaction(delTransactions[0].id, delTransactions[0])
      } else {
        this.closeModal();
      }
    })
    console.log('current note', this.note)
  }
```

My test is as follows:

```
  it('should initialize properly when updating', () => {
    let testTransactions = [{id: 1}]
    let dueDate = '1/2/3'
    let testNote = 'Test'
    component.deliverableTransactions = testTransactions
    component.dueDate = dueDate
    component.note = testNote

    spyOn(component, 'createNotes').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(component, 'createDelTransactions').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(noteService, 'createNote').and.returnValue(true);
    spyOn(noteService, 'getNoteCreated').and.returnValue({subscribe: () => true});
    spyOn(deliverableTransactionService, 'getUpdateDeliverableTransactionStatus').and.returnValue({subscribe: () => true});

    component.updateTransactions();

    expect(component.createNotes).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.createDelTransactions).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(noteService.createNote).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(noteService.getNoteCreated).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(deliverableTransactionService.getUpdateDeliverableTransactionStatus).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

And I've defined the various services in:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChangeDueDateComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    deliverableTransactionService = TestBed.get(DeliverableTransactionService);
    noteService = TestBed.get(NoteService);
    activeModal = TestBed.get(NgbActiveModal);
  }));
```

Yet, when I run the test, I get an error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ChangeDueDateComponent should initialize properly when updating FAILED
        Error: <spyOn> : getNoteCreated() method does not exist
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Could you cut this down to a [mcve], including the service you're spying on? Also note that you can return `of(true)` instead of building an object with a `subscribe` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why `getNoteCreated` is not found on `noteService`. Is it supposed to be there?

Regardless, you can avoid the error by creating the spy in this way:

```
noteService.getNoteCreated = jasmine.createSpy().and
  .returnValue({subscribe: () => true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return the subscription from `getNoteValue` instead of an `Observable`.

Change your spy this way :

```
spyOn(noteService, 'getNoteCreated').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true));
```

Comment: Helpful, but still gives the same error that it can't find `getNoteCreated`

Comment: This isn't an answer; the error is on *setting up* the spy, it's not even getting to the return value.

Comment: @Shamoon Are you sure that, your app works properly without any errors?

Comment: Yes - the app does what it's supposed to without errors